# Loading images from URL via Kingfisher on iWatch takes a long time

Tags: swift, watchkit, watch, kingfisher

I'm working on Watch app that has **WKInterfaceTable**, and in each cell of the table, I have to load an image from URL,

I used [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher) to load the images like this:

```
self.mainGroup.setBackgroundImage(defualt_Image) //placeholder image

    if let placeUrl = URL(string: urlString) {

        _ = KingfisherManager.shared.retrieveImage(with: placeUrl, options: nil, progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: { (image, error, cacheType, imageURL) in

            if image != nil {

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.mainGroup.setBackgroundImage(image)
            }
             }
        })

    }
```

this code is called when I set up the table.

**The problem** is the image took about 20 seconds to be loaded,

I searched a lot for this problem but there are no useful answers.

Did anyone face the same problem on **iWatch**?

Please HELP!

thanks.

Comment: retrieveImage is an async method. make sure you update the UI from the main thread

Comment: @LeoDabus hi, thanks for your answer, I update my code, but unfortunately, no changes happen and the images still take a very long time to be loaded, please check my updated code

Answer (score 0):

try this code. it will work.

```
   DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
                self.mainGroup.setBackgroundImage(image)
            })
```